# Lua 5.1 Bytecode - How are doubles encoded?

Tags: encoding, lua, compiler-construction

I've recently been creating a Lua compiler (in lua) for version 5.1 and I am having a few issues with encoding numbers in constants, I have read in multiple places online that the encoding they use is double-precision floats however I cannot seem to get my encoding to match with theirs.

If anyone could give me more information on how they encode their numbers that'd be amazing!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is easily googlable: `IEEE-754` + `Lua`.  [For example](https://github.com/fperrad/lua-MessagePack/blob/master/src/MessagePack.lua#L423-L457)

Comment: I'm not sure if you fully read my question, however I said that I know they use double-precision floats however nothing I have made, nor that I have found online, has replicated what they seem to be using.

Comment: Your question is "how they encode their numbers?", and the answer is "they encode numbers in IEEE-754 format".  Indeed, it's easy to check that Lua bytecode contains IEEE-754 representation of numbers.  Just create bytecode with `string.dump(f)` and you will successfully find all floating point constants used by function `f()` as substrings in its bytecode.  The link I gave contains a code how to build IEEE-754 representation for arbitrary floating point number in Lua 5.1.  Of course, IEEE-754 depends on endianness.  What exactly is the problem you can't solve?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I ended up doing more research into the example you gave me and it turns out someone had adapted it for lua 5.1 bytecode and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the response.